# Android center TextView horizontally while keeping left align

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

As my title describes, I want the text in a TextView to be horizontally centered in it's parent element while keeping the text left aligned:

So this:

```
|     Text     |
|   TextText   |
```

becomes this:

```
|   Text       |
|   TextText   |
```

Is this possible with Android?

This is my current layout:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="0.25"
  android:background="@drawable/table_cell"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="@string/table_last_training" />
```

Thanks in advance,
McFarlane

Comment: You likely need to create a custom view class and handle the TextView drawing parameters in onDraw, as far a I know it is the only way of doing it because you will have to handle shifting based on screen/layout dimensions which are only determined after onMeasure. That is unless you really want to hack it together and in that case you could create a method that adds spaces as padding as needed. If you want, I can show an answer of how you could do the hacked version (though I would never recommend it :P). There are also likely a few ways to do this using pure xml, but I see that getting messy.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for this layout.

|   Text       |
|   TextText   |

I change the layout_height to wrap_content. Also added inside the TableRow.
Personally I don't like TableLayout as it's unpredictable and troublesome, particularly when using merged columns, colspan.
 I prefer using LinearLayout with layout_weight  for each row.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_shape" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape3"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.375" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:text="Text" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.375" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape3"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.375" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:text="Text Text" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.375" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: my parent cell is a TableRow.

I've tried your solution 1, because TableRow extends Linear Layout but it does not work. 1st, it suddenly fills the whole vertical screen height and 2nd, it is not horizontally centered. The "dummy Views" just act as a margin to the TextView.

I've also tried wrapping the TextView with a RelativeView insinde the TableRow, but your solution doesn't center anything in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already tried this. The Problem is, that those empty Views act like a 37,5% padding of the text view. This results in the TextView not beeing actually centered by it's content.

Comment: or maybe you could add the code or post the picture of your designed layout result? sorry I still cannot imagine .

Comment: from your question. you want the layout to be like: | Text | | TextText | in the 2nd format? in that case, the 1st TableRow 
"Text" is not centered, only 2nd TableRow "Text Text" is centered? or you meant both "Text" and "Text Text" are inside the same element?  if you know the exact width of the row, you can use that in the layout_width, set gravity="center" and use layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight in the parent layout (remove the 2 padding Views)?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String hackSpace(Context context, float textSize, String text) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setTextSize(textSize);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams textViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    String[] sentences = text.split("\n");
    //calculate space width
    textView.setText(" ");
    textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int slice = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
    //calculate each sentence
    int[] sentencesWidth = new int[sentences.length];
    //store max width
    int maxWidth = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        textView.setText(sentences[i]);
        textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        sentencesWidth[i] = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
        if (sentencesWidth[i] > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = sentencesWidth[i];
        }
    }
    //add space after each sentence if necessary
    for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        int spaceNum = (maxWidth - sentencesWidth[i]) / slice;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 0; k < spaceNum; k++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sentences[i] += sb.toString();
    }
    //rebuild String
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        sb.append(sentences[i]);
        if (i != sentences.length - 1) {
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Just use hackSpace(Context,float,String) to add space in your sentences before set them into TextView.